# VS code - highlight selected word in minimap

Tags: visual-studio-code, highlight

Just shifted to VS code from Atom (nostalgia :P).
 I'm looking for a way to highlight selected word in minimap. Any idea how to get [this](https://atom.io/packages/minimap-highlight-selected) for VS code?

[image]

Comment: Looking for similar thing

Comment: Yeah, seems like there is no similar extension.

Answer (score 8):

I use the [`mde.select-highlight-minimap`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mde.select-highlight-minimap) plugin, which works great.

[image: VS code - highlight selected word in minimap]

Comment: this is not really the same thing. It puts a marker on the scrollbar, not the mini map. And as of VS Code 1.70.1 (or earlier) this is already a built-in feature, except the default marker in the scroll bar seems to be quite dull. This scrollbar-marker is not at all as helpful as the Atom implementation, where the highlight border was rendered directly into the Minimap, because I scroll to the location on the minimap where the selected item is, I still have to visually scan the code to find the item I wanted. Helps instead to use a theme with `focusBorder` or `contrastActiveBorder` enabled

Answer (score 4):

It is not available yet. But this feature request is tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84151).

Answer (score 1):

From this PR: [Minimap - highlight all instances of selected word](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/132584)  a colorCustomization is being added to highlight other occurrences of the selected word:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "minimap.selectionOccurrenceHighlight": "#ff0000"
}
```

Should be in Stable v1.61, in Insiders now.